# Python socket server on azure vm

Tags: python, azure, sockets, virtual-machine

I have an azure vm running Linux (ubuntu 18.04) LTS and i have created a python socket server binding a socket with

```
socket.bind(('localhost', 10000))
```

but when i try to connect from another script via

```
socket.connect(ip,10000)
```

the server reject the connection.

How do i solve this?

I already tried to open the port on my wm with

```
az vm open-port --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myVM --port 10000
```

But the server still refuse my connection.

Client script:

```
import socket
import threading

class Client:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    def sendData(self):
        while True:
            self.sock.send(bytes(input("")))

    def __init__(self):
        self.sock.connect(('serverip', 10000))
        iThread = threading.Thread(target=self.sendData)
        iThread.daemon = True
        iThread.start()

        while True:
            data = self.sock.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            print(data)

client = Client()
```

Server script:

```
import socket
import threading
import random

def getuserdata(b):
    #function that works
    return a

class Server:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    connections = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.sock.bind(('localhost', 10000))
        self.sock.listen(1)
        print (self.sock.getsockname())

    def handler(self, c , a):
        while True:
            try:
                data = c.recv(1024)
            except:
                self.connections.remove(c)
                c.close()
                print(str(a[0]) + ":" + str(a[1]), "disconnected")
                print("lobby has " + str(len(self.connections)) + " players connected")
                break
            #loop per client
            #for connection in self.connections:
            #    connection.send(data)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if len(self.connections) < 8:
                c , a = self.sock.accept()
                cThread = threading.Thread(target=self.handler , args=(c,a))
                cThread.daemon = True
                cThread.start()
                self.connections.append(c)
                print(str(a[0]) + ":" + str(a[1]) , "connected")
                print("lobby has " + str(len(self.connections)) + " players connected")
            #loop del server
            else:
                break
        print("lobby piena")
        list= getuserdata(8)
        for index, player in enumerate(self.connections):
            player.send(bytes(list[index]))
        while True:
            pass

server = Server()
server.run()
```

Comment: What family did you use for the socket when creating it? Also, you might want to use [socketserver](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#module-socketserver) instead.

Comment: Please add the client and server script for more details.

Comment: sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `0.0.0.0` or the IP address of your Azure Ubuntu VM instead of `localhost` as server socket bind host.

If you use `localhost` as host bind by socket server, then just only client on the same machine can connect to your server, because `localhost` means `127.0.0.1` which only allow client connect to the server IP address `127.0.0.1`.

Meanwhile, you need to refer to the offical documents [`Tutorial: Create and manage Azure virtual networks for Linux virtual machines with the Azure CLI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-virtual-network) or [`How to open ports to a virtual machine with the Azure portal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal) to add an inbound rule in the NSG setting of networking via Azure CLI or on portal.